# How to convert string to bytes32 in web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs

I have a contract with a public variable that's bytes32.  If I enter the value 20160528 then it auto converts to bytes32.  Is there anyway to convert it back from the nodejs terminal?  I've been trying

```
web3.toAscii(testInstance.Date.call())
```

but it just gives me nonsense.  Here is the the test code:

```
contract test {
  bytes32 public Date;

  function test(bytes32 _date){
      Date=_date; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Convert back to `20160528` ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### For web3 0.x:

You need to use `web3.fromAscii(val)` to write correct `bytes32` input to contract.

And you are right, anyone can read it with `web3.toAscii(val)`.

Full web3.js code in terms of your designations:

```
//sets bytes32
testInstance.test.sendTransaction(web3.fromAscii("20160528"), options);

//gets bytes32
testInstance.Date.call(function(err, val) {
    if  (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(web3.toAscii(val));
    // will print "20160528"
 });
```

#### For web3 1.0:

*Note: `fromAscii` has been deprecated*

You need to use `web3.utils.asciiToHex(val)` to write correct `bytes32` input to contract.

And you are right, anyone can read it with `web3.utils.hexToAscii(val)`.

Full web3.js code in terms of your designations:

```
//sets bytes32
testInstance.methods.test(web3.utils.asciiToHex("20160528")).send(options);

//gets bytes32
testInstance.methods.Date().call(function(err, val) {
    if  (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(web3.utils.hexToAscii(val));
    // will print "20160528"
 });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: hex.substring is not a function` when trying to log `val`, which seems to be a complex object. Have things changed in web3 recently?

Comment: @StanJames I've updated my answer with the code for web3 1.0. Previous one was for web 0.x

Comment: How to deal with trailing zeroes?

Comment: I'm getting `Error: incorrect data length ` Does this method also make the bytes32 the right length somehow?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I'm getting the same. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @PatrickCollins The string must be 32-bytes long. Please fill remaining space with null-characters denoted using `\0`, or any other character you wish. For example, here is a valid bytes32: `web3.utils.asciiToHex("Hello, World! :)\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")`

Comment: @AlexC See my comment above^