# Define variables inside tests for contract

Tags: solidity, testrpc

I write a bit more than plain contract on solidity and working on test to it. I faced with issue to put pass variables inside.

If I define variable as `let` I receive compilation error like this:

> BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a number: entity

My attempts to define it as solidity variable are failed, seems test doesn't support any type except `let`

Here is a sample of the contract and test for it.

```
contract Market {

    struct good {
        address owner;
        bytes32 goodName;
        uint amount;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => good[]) market;

    uint counter;

    function Market() {}

    function putGood(bytes32 name, address owner, uint quantity) public returns (uint) {
        good memory newGood = good(owner, name, quantity);
        market[name].push(newGood);
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }

  function getGood(bytes32 good) public view returns (bytes32, uint)     {
    return (market[good].owner, market[good].goodName, market[good].amount);
}
}
```

Related test

```
const Market = artifacts.require('../test/Market.sol')

contract('Market', function(accounts) {


let market;

beforeEach(`create subject instance before each test`, async function() {
    market = await Market.new();
})

it(`client put good on the market - one good - one good is available on the market`, async function() {
    let testGood = stringToUint("test good");

    await market.putGood(testGood, accounts[0], 1);

    let good = await market.getGood(testGood);

    assert.equals(good.owner, accounts[0]);
})
```

Could you please help me with place where I can learn more about defning different types in solidity tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information about Solidity elementary types is here: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#types.

1. You can learn how to set/get bytes32 from web3 here: [web3 return bytes32 string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23058/web3-return-bytes32-string/23110#23110)
2. address in Solidity -> "0x..." string in Javascript
3. Other inputs in Solidity: bool, int/uint, string have the similar types in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks! web3.toUtf8() and web3.fromAscii() functions work are what I need. For structures I use `let data` with access to elements as data[0]